# When Dirac function is in $H^{-m}(R^n)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

If Dirac function $\delta\in H^{-m}(R^n)$,please give the range of $m$?

Comment: This is a very reasonable question... downvotes are a mystery.

Comment: @Paul Although guessing reasons for downvotes isn't a productive activity, I remark that despite the presence of mathematical content, the question completely lacks the poster's thoughts on said content. Maybe it was written in a hurry and Darry will do better next time. This one has been answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the Fourier transform of $\delta_0$ is the constant equal to $1$. So the problem is to see whether $(1+|x|^2)^{s/2}$ is integrable over $\Bbb R^n$. As this function is radial, we can reduce this to a problem of integration over the real line.

Comment: @ Davide Giraudo：Thank you!